# FILE PERMISSION FOR UNIX

Tags: file, unix, permissions

How to add permission for the User can read, write, and execute; the Group can read; and the Other users can't do anything?

Answer (score 3):

(I would suggest this question is better asked at either the Unix or SuperUser StackExchange sites)

Chmod is your friend here.

To quote from http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html :

```
chmod g+w myfile
```

give group write permission to "myfile", leaving all other permission flags alone

```
chmod g-rw myfile
```

remove read and write access to "myfile", leaving all other permission flags alone

```
chmod g+rwxs mydir
```

give full group read/write access to directory "mydir", also setting the set-groupID flag so that directories created inside it inherit the group

```
chmod u=rw,go= privatefile
```

explicitly give user read/write access, and revoke all group and other access, to file 'privatefile'

```
chmod -R g+rw .
```

give group read write access to this directory, and everything inside of it (-R = recursive)

```
chgrp -R medi .
```

change the ownership of this directory to group 'medi' and everything inside of it (-R = recursive). The person issuing this command must own all the files or it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Command line ;

chmod 740 filename

Comment: How do you that in symbolic representation?

Comment: `read=4, write=2, execute=1`. You make the addition among the permissions you want to give to each block. 7=read+write+execute, 6=read+write...

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want it in symbolic notation:

chmod u=rwx,g=r,o= file